# "Could not find installable ISAM" after adding "IMEX=1" to connection string

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, adodb

I'm trying to open an ADODB connection to an Access 2010 database:

```
    public void openConnection()
    {
        conn = new ADODB.Connection();
        string dbPath = @"T:\somePath\sigilDB.accdb";

        string connString=string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"IMEX=1\"",dbPath);
        conn.Open(connString);
    }
```

The `conn.Open()` call gives me the error:

```
Could not find installable ISAM
```

This started when I added the `Extended Properties=\"IMEX=1\"` to the connection string, so that mixed data types in columns will be read as strings.  Is there a different way that I need to add this option to the connection string?

Comment: Nt sure if it's needed but you are missing the trailing `;` from the end.

Comment: I've only ever seen the `IMEX` property in relation to Excel connections. When reading from an Access database there are no "mixed data types" for a given column because the table's column definitions control the "type" of data returned.

Comment: @GordThompson, I think that's an adequate explanation to post as an answer.

Comment: No need, your answer is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `IMEX` simply isn't one of the extended properties for the ACE provider.

In this case, it's not necessary; so far, my testing confirms that mixed data types are handled correctly when queried from Access using ADODB.

EDIT: just spotted Gord Thompson's comment indicating the same.